# Database schema question

Tags: mysql, refactoring, schema

I have a table in a mysql database which contains exchange rates. Currently it is defined like this:

```
date | currency | rate
```

These rates use some base currency. Now I need to also store rates for another base currency. Is it better to create a separate table or use one table? What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: Can you include some sample data that would be in the table?

Comment: Interesting question, because logic dictates that there should be an efficient way to store all data without having to resort to duplicates, because exchange rates work both ways. +1.

Comment: @Dirk: `2011-07-20 | AUD | 30.0056  ||
      
2011-07-20 | CAD | 29.4461`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a new column currency_from which is the start currency and change currency to currency_to which would be the currency being changed to

Comment: the pros of this is your currency convertor doesn't need to keep track of different table names for different conversion types AND you only have to do one conversion rather than 2 if you decide to keep as is and convert to your known currency and then convert to the desired currency.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need to store this with two base currencies? If you know the rate from dollars to euros, and euros to pounds, you can derive dollars to pounds.

If you do have to store both base rates, i_forget's answer is clearly right - you want your currency conversion code to be identical, not have to substitute table names depending on which currency you're using - if you have to go to 2 currencies, you have to consider the possibility you have to go to 200 currencies.

Comment: +1 Agreed. Not sure why you'd need to store rates in a second base currency, @planetp. If you have some source providing fx rates in a different base currency, consider converting them into *your* base before persisting them.

Comment: -1 disagreed. Currency conversion is not temperature conversion. You need to store the rate for each currency pair for each date or unit of time.

Comment: @TomL - it's a question, not an answer. If you're tracking historical transactions, you do indeed need to store the rate for each currency; if all you're doing is calculating hypothetical values, you may not need it.

Comment: @djacobson: Actually I use official exchange rates such as [these](http://cbr.ru/eng/currency_base/daily.aspx?C_month=07&C_year=2011&date_req=20.07.2011). How best to store suchlike data from several sources?

Comment: @planetp In your question, you said this: *"These rates use some base currency. Now I need to also store rates for another base currency"*, which led me to believe that you have a single base currency you are currently / wish to use to store exchange rates. Is that true? If so, what is that currency?